# Paste into iFrame at caret position

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to recreate the 'Paste from work' functionality in Wordpress for my clients WISIWIG editor. It uses an iframe for the editor. I can added the pasted code at the beginning or end of the current iframe, but i'd like to be able to paste it at the caret position.

It's clearly possible as you can do this in wordpress, does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What editor it is (e.g. ckEditor, TinyMCE, ...)? If it's one of those known, it's very likely that its API has a relevant function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based my answer on this http://help.dottoro.com/ljnuatqw.php