# Get caret HTML position in contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, caret

I am having troubles figuring out how to get caret position in a DIV container that contains HTML tags.

I am using this JavaScript function to do that:

```
function  getCaretPosition()
{
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt)
    {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var selectedObj = window.getSelection();
            var rangeCount = 0;
            var childNodes = selectedObj.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes;
            for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++)
            {
                if (childNodes[i] == selectedObj.anchorNode)
                {
                        break;
                    }
                        if(childNodes[i].outerHTML)
                        {
                rangeCount += childNodes[i].outerHTML.length;
            }
            else if(childNodes[i].nodeType == 3)
            {
                            rangeCount += childNodes[i].textContent.length;                       
            }
        }
        return range.startOffset + rangeCount;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

However, it finds a caret position of the text in my DIV container, when I need to find the caret position including HTML tags.
For example:

```
<DIV class="peCont" contenteditable="true">Text goes here along with <b>some <i>HTML</i> tags</b>.</DIV>;
```

(*please note, that HTML tags are normal tags and are not displayed on the screen when the function is returning caret position*)

If I click right between H and TML, the aforementioned function will find caret position without any problems. But I am getting the contents of DIV box in HTML format (including all tags), and if I want to insert something at that caret's position, I will be off by a few or many characters.

I went through many posts, but all I could find is either <TEXTAREA> caret postions, or functions similar to what I have posted. So far I still cannot find a solution to get a caret position in a text that has HTML formatting.

Can anyone help, please?

PS. Here's JQuery/Javascript code that I wrote for the link button:

```
$('#pageEditor').on('click', '.linkURL', function()
{
    var cursorPosition;
    cursorPosition = getCaretPosition();
    var contentID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var userSelected = getSelectionHtml();
    var checkLink = userSelected.search('</a>');
    var anchorTag = 0;
    if(checkLink == -1)
    {
        var currentContents = $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html();
        var indexOfSelection = currentContents.indexOf(userSelected);
        var getPossibleAnchor = currentContents.slice(indexOfSelection, indexOfSelection+userSelected.length+6);
        anchorTag = getPossibleAnchor.search('</a>');
    }

    if(checkLink > 0 || anchorTag > 0)
    {
        //alert(checkLink);
        document.execCommand('unlink', false, false);

    }
    else
    {
        $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').append('<div id="linkEntry"><label for="urlLink">Please enter URL for the link:<label><input type="text" id="urlLink" /></div>');
        $('#linkEntry').dialog({
             buttons: { 
                "Ok": function() 
                {
                    var attribute = $('#urlLink').val();
                    var newContentWithLink = '';
                    if(attribute != '')
                    {
                        if(userSelected != '')
                        {
                            var currentContent = $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html();
                            var replacement = '<a href="'+attribute+'">'+userSelected+'</a>';
                            newContentWithLink = currentContent.replace(userSelected, replacement);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var currentTextContent = $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html();
                            var userLink = '<a href="'+attribute+'">'+attribute+'</a>';
                            if(cursorPosition > 0)
                            {
                                var contentBegin = currentTextContent.slice(0,cursorPosition);
                                var contentEnd = currentTextContent.slice(cursorPosition,currentTextContent.length);
                                newContentWithLink = contentBegin+userLink+contentEnd;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                newContentWithLink = attribute+currentTextContent;
                            }
                        }
                        $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').empty();
                        $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html(newContentWithLink);
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                } },
             closeOnEscape:true,
             modal:true,
             resizable:false,
             show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
             hide: { effect: 'drop', direction: "down" },
             width:460,
             closeText:'hide',
             close: function()
             {
                $(this).remove();
             }
        });

        $('#linkEntry').on('keypress', function(urlEnter)
        {
            if(urlEnter.which == 13)
            {
                var attribute = $('#urlLink').val();
                var newContentWithLink = '';
                if(userSelected != '')
                {
                    var currentContent = $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html();
                    var replacement = '<a href="'+attribute+'">'+userSelected+'</a>';
                    newContentWithLink = currentContent.replace(userSelected, replacement);
                }
                else
                {
                    var currentTextContent = $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html();
                    var userLink = '<a href="'+attribute+'">'+attribute+'</a>';
                    if(cursorPosition > 0)
                    {
                        var contentBegin = currentTextContent.slice(0,cursorPosition);
                        var contentEnd = currentTextContent.slice(cursorPosition,currentTextContent.length);
                        newContentWithLink = contentBegin+userLink+contentEnd;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newContentWithLink = attribute+currentTextContent;
                    }
                }
                $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').empty();
                $('#'+contentID+' .peCont').html(newContentWithLink);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially meaningless: there are more than one different valid HTML string representations of the contents of your `<div>`, and the original HTML content sent by the server (if that's what you're after) is inaccessible from the DOM (you'd have to do some nasty Ajax thing to get a new copy of the page and then parse the response). What exactly are you intending to do with this position once you've got it?

Comment: I am trying to insert some HTML formatting - let's say, an anchor. So I click between H and TML, and let's say hypothetically, its position is 10. Now a window pop up, user enters URL, hits Enter and I want to insert it back into my site- (but here's a problem - HTML is positioned at 80 - that's all those HTML tags). Now I am inserting an anchor at index 10, because that's what the script I am using does - which means results are unpredictable. I am trying to make custom CMS.

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is save the selection range before popping up the dialog. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726579/insert-html-when-the-caret-was-in-a-content-editable-div. And here's how to handle a potential IE pitfall: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337752/inserting-text-into-an-editable-iframe-at-the-caret-position-ie

Comment: The first link does not work. I am using JQuery modal dialog box - where user enters enters their URL. Every time they hit submit, the link is inserted at the beginning of the text, not current caret position. I am going to alter my question and add the code for the link button that I have created above.

Comment: You need to store the caret position before the editable `<div>` loses focus.

Comment: I did assign cursorPosition = saveSelection(); or do I have to do it before the user even clicks on the button?

Comment: Yes, before the click event fires, at least. I think `mousedown` is early enough.

Comment: Obviously I am doing something wrong. It still inserts the link at the beginning of the `<DIV>` container. I am very new with javascript and JQuery, so I am not getting where the proper placement will occur. I know that JQuery is event-based - so I placed `var cursorPosition = saveSelection();` when I just click inside of the `<DIV>`, not the link button and when I `alert(cursorPosition);` - the alert box is blank

Answer (score -1):

I created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zupa/YGBhG/) for you that does what you want.

This should work in recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

It's your homework to add Opera and IE support if you need.